# The current path, account/login/, didn't match any of these?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm trying to access my project (local), and I am getting this traceback:

traceback

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/
Using the URLconf defined in tutorial.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
[name='login_redirect'] 
admin/ 
account/ ^$ 
account/ ^login$ 
account/ ^logout$ 
account/ ^register$ [name='register'] 
account/ ^profile$ [name='view_profile'] 
account/ ^profile/edit$ [name='edit_profile'] 
account/ ^change-password$ [name='change_password'] 
account/ ^reset-password$ [name='reset_password'] 
account/ ^reset-password/done$ [name='password_reset_done'] 
account/ ^reset-password/confirm(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A- Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,23})/$ [name='password_reset_confirm'] 
account/ ^reset-password/complete$ [name='password_reset_complete'] 
The current path, account/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

Main/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from tutorial import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.login_redirect, name='login_redirect'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('account/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import (

PasswordResetView,
PasswordResetDoneView,
PasswordResetConfirmView,
PasswordResetCompleteView,

)

from django.urls import re_path


urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.home),
url(r'^login$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html')),
url(r'^logout$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html')),
url(r'^register$', views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^profile$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
url(r'^profile/edit$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
url(r'^change-password$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
url(r'^reset-password$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='reset_password'),
url(r'^reset-password/done$', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^reset-password/confirm(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,23})/$',
    PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^reset-password/complete$', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

middleware.py

```
import re
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class LoginRequiredMiddleware:

def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response

def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    assert hasattr(request, 'user')

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if True:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/login'
LOGIN_URL = '/account/login/'
```

What is the problem here?. The redirect works, I have a feeling its in urlpatterns but cannot for the life figure it out. Driving me crazy today. Thanks for the help and sorry for the essay!

Comment: Note that [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) is where requests are redirect following a successful login, so you should set it to something different than your login URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `LOGIN_URL` setting has a trailing slash:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/account/login/'
```

But your URL pattern for `login` does not allow a trailing slash.

```
url(r'^login$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html')),
```

You could remove the slash from the `LOGIN_URL`. However, the usual practice in Django is to include a trailing slash in URLs. Then, the default behaviour will redirect any requests from `/accounts/login` to `/accounts/login/` with a trailing slash.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. added / to my urls and login_redirect_url = /account/ and login_url = /account/login/

Comment: Note that the Django help pages use `/accounts/`, not `/account/`.